# SendMessage fail using RegisterWindowMessage API

Tags: c#, c++, sendmessage

I am sending a window message from a C# application to a C++ Win32 application. I am using a message via the `RegisterWindowMessage()` API.

The string value transfers from C# to C++, but on the C++ side I could not convert it back to a string.

C#

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

_sendMessageID = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_MSG_TEST");

public void SendMessage()
{
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.StringToBSTR("Hello");
    SendMessage((IntPtr)0xffff, (int)_sendMessageID, IntPtr.Zero, buffer);
}
```

C++

```cpp
UINT WM_MSG_AA = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_MSG_TEST");

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_MSG_TEST)
    {
        BSTR* pcds = (BSTR*)lParam;
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue?

I also refer below link for fix issue but it could't help.

[C# SendMessage to C++ WinProc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653658/c-sharp-sendmessage-to-c-winproc)

[Send message to a hwnd in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388340/send-message-to-a-hwnd-in-c-sharp)

```
// WindowCreationCode

BOOL ProcessNextMessage()
{   
    MSG msg;
    GetMessage(&(msg), _hWnd, 0, 0);
    TranslateMessage(&(msg));
    DispatchMessage(&(msg));
    return TRUE;
}
int Create(){
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    _hInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    WNDCLASS wcex = { 0 };
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = _hInst;
    wcex.lpszClassName = c_szClassName;

    if (!GetClassInfo(wcex.hInstance, wcex.lpszClassName, &wcex))
    {
        if (!RegisterClass(&wcex))
        {
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
        else
        {
            return S_OK;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    _hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        c_szClassName,
        "ACTXAUTODRIVER",
        WS_DLGFRAME ,
        1, 1, 1, 1,
        NULL,
        NULL, _hInst, NULL);

        ShowWindow(_hWnd, SW_HIDE);

        while (ProcessNextMessage())
        {
        }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: Pointers cannot be valid across process boundaries.  Get ahead by using a better process interop mechanism, a named pipe works well in both languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send raw memory pointers across process boundaries like you are attempting to do. Even though you are converting your C# string data to a `BSTR` allocated by the OS, the allocated memory is still only valid in the address space of the process that allocated it.

Your string data must be **marshaled** from one process's address space to the other process's address space.  COM handles that for you automatically when it passes `BSTR` values over process boundaries. But with window messages, only certain messages are marshaled automatically by the OS, and messages created with `RegisterWindowMessage()` are not marshaled.

For what you are attempting, use [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-copydata) instead, which is marshaled.  However, you should NEVER broadcast (use `(IntPtr)0xffff` aka `HWND_BROADCAST` as the target window) a `WM_COPYDATA` message! Bad things can happen if unsuspecting apps receive `WM_COPYDATA` messages they are not prepared to handle correctly.

Have your C# code find the *specific* window it is actually interested in for your C++ app (from `FindWindow/Ex()`, etc) and then send `WM_COPYDATA` to only that window and no others. You can use `RegisterWindowMessage()` to create a unique value for use in the `COPYDATASTRUCT::dwData` field to differentiate your use of `WM_COPYDATA` from other people's use of `WM_COPYDATA`. Make your C++ code ignore any `WM_COPYDATA` message whose `dwData` value is not recognized.

Try something more like this:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr dwData;
    public int cbData;
    public IntPtr lpData;
}

const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

_cdsDataID = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_MSG_TEST");

public void SendMessage() {
    if (_cdsDataID == IntPtr.Zero) return;
    IntPtr TargetWnd = ...; // FindWindow(), etc
    if (TargetWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return;
    string s = "Hello";
    COPYDATASTRUCT copyData = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
    copyData.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(s);
    if (copyData.lpData != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        copyData.dwData = _cdsDataID;
        copyData.cbData = (s.Length + 1) * 2;
        IntPtr copyDataBuff = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(copyData));
        if (copyDataBuff != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(copyData, copyDataBuff, false);
            SendMessage(TargetWnd, WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, copyDataBuff);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(copyDataBuff);
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(copyData.lpData);
    }
}
```

```cpp
const UINT uiDataID = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_MSG_TEST");

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_COPYDATA) 
    {
        LPCOPYDATASTRUCT pcds = (LPCOPYDATASTRUCT) lParam;
        if ((pcds->dwData == WM_MSG_TEST) && (WM_MSG_TEST != 0))
        {
            WCHAR* pstr = (WCHAR*) pcds->lpData;
            ...
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I can not use WM_COPYDATA. My window is not visible at screen. So it is not able the receive message while window is hide. Is there any way to Send message if my window is hide _hWnd = CreateWindowEx(  WS_EX_TOPMOST,
  c_szClassName,
  "ACTXAUTODRIVER",
  WS_DLGFRAME ,
  1, 1, 1, 1,
  NULL,
  NULL, _hInst, NULL);ShowWindow(_hWnd, SW_HIDE);

Comment: I Added my window WindowCreationCode for detail infromation

Comment: @mahen a window does not have to be visible to receive any message, including `WM_COPYDATA`. Your C# code can use `FindWindowEx()` to find a window by its class name and/or title, even if it is hidden.

Comment: You are right, but although it s not able to receive message when window is hide.I found the window by FindWindowEx but sendmessage message not received.

Comment: @mahen then you are going something wrong, because this technique works fine when used correctly. A window's visibility does not affect its ability to receive messages

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer string with your custom message with global atom - see `GlobalAddAtom` API. You get integer value from GlobalAddAtom (atom number) and give the string as input parameter. Then `SendMessage` transmits the atom as `WPARAM` or `LPARAM`. The other side decodes the atom to string with `GlobalGetAtomName`. Finally call `GlobalDeleteAtom` to free the resource.

Comment: Although this "works", atom tables have fairly limited space available, and atoms themselves have very limited sizes. You should not use atoms in this fashion for cross-process interop

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree, but for short strings it is "another" method - with compact implementation.